# can not load dotEnv file from assets in released app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have created a dotEnv file in root of project and added that file to `pubspec.yaml` file like this:

```
  assets:
    - dotEnv.develop
```

then I reference it in main.dart file this way:

```
void main() async{
  await dotenv.load(fileName: "dotEnv.develop");

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

but the the released app can not find dotEnv.develop file, however it exists in assets folder as this image shows:
[image]

and in console of chrome I get this error:

```
main.dart.js:41783 Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/dotEnv.develop" (404)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

now my flutter sdk version is  3.0.5

Comment: Which dot-env package are you using? Also, how are you loading the `dotEnv.develop` file (the source code)?

Comment: I use `flutter_dotenv 5.0.2` and  I use this in main(): ` await dotenv.load(fileName: "assets/dotEnv.develop");`

Comment: Including environment secrets in a plain text file in a production app is bad practice. You should be using `--dart-define` to pass environment variables to your production build.

Comment: For those who haven't seen that bit about dart-define that @Abion47 mentioned: https://dartcode.org/docs/using-dart-define-in-flutter/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `dotEnv.develop` is in the root folder and you're trying to load it from the `assets` folder.

Instead of:

```dart
await dotenv.load(fileName: "assets/dotEnv.develop");
```

Do the following instead:

```dart
await dotenv.load(fileName: "dotEnv.develop");
```

Comment: thank you, but I've also tried this, I copy and pasted the file in `root`, in `assets`, and in `assets/assets` and I changed reference `await dotenv.load(fileName: "...");` and 404 error is still persists, however the location that error says, the file is there!

Comment: Did you try already `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it.

Comment: Weird... testing on my machine it works on the web platform building in release mode. Would you please [edit] your question and add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Could it be related to the version of flutter sdk? it's  2.10.4

Comment: It's possible. I think `web` is still experimental on 2.x, but I'm not sure. I've tested it with the latest version, 3.0.5.

Comment: Thank you @lepsch. I added image and code and I'll try updating sdk. It would be greate If there was another way to define server url in deployed app and my goal of using env was for server url in production which is unknown now and it's localhost now, something like config.php that I can change the server address any time and it's not hardcoded in application

Answer (score 0):

Create a  .env file inside of the root of your project
and write this at it

```
API_URL=localhost:3000
```

then add the .env file to pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
- .env
```

this is [resource](https://developer.school/tutorials/how-to-use-environment-variables-with-flutter-dotenv)

Answer (score 0):

Find the problem in mine.
It doesn't find ".env" but "env".
Change it to:

```
await dotenv.load(fileName: "assets/env");

assets:
   - assets/env
```